# Degree of field extension and rational function field

Tags: extension-field, rational-functions

Suppose that $k$ and $k'$ are fields such that $k\subset k'$ and $[k':k]=n$, where $n$ is an positive integer.

Do we have $[k'(x):k(x)]=[k':k]$? Why?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Could you please explain the meaning of $[k':k]=n$?

Comment: It's the degree of extension, i.e. the dimension of $k'$ as a $k$-vector space is $n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you tagged the question with *rational-functions* I assume that $x$ is an indeterminate (i.e. an element that is transcendental over $k$ and hence also over $k'$).

Yes. It probably is not a surpise that a $k$-basis $\mathcal{B}$ of $k'$ is also a $k(x)$ basis of $k'(x)$. We get there for example as follows.

1. Writing individual coefficients of polynomials $\in k'[x]$ in terms of $\mathcal{B}$ shows that $k'[x]$ is a free $k[x]$-module with basis $\mathcal{B}$.
2. Consequently $\mathcal{B}$ is  linearly independent as a subset of $k'(x)$ viewed as a vector space over the subfield $k(x)$. This is because we can clear the denominators of the coefficients of an eventual linear dependency relation reducing this to the case where there would be a linear dependency relation with coefficients from $k[x]$. In violation of step 1.
3. If $f(x)$ is an arbitrary non-zero polynomial $\in k'[x]$, I claim that $f(x)$ is a factor of a polynomial from $k[x]$. Consider the quotient $V=k'[x]/\langle f(x)\rangle$ as a module over both $k[x]$ and $k'[x]$. Because $\dim_k V<\infty$ the annihilator ideal $$I=\{a(x)\in k[x]\mid a(x)V=0\}$$ is non-trivial. As $k[x]$ is a PID $I$ is generated by a polynomial $g(x)$. The annihilator $I'$ of $V$ as a $k'[x]$-module is generated by $f(x)$. As $I\subset I'$ we must have $f(x)\mid g(x)$.
4. Let $z=p(x)/q(x)\in k'(x), p,q\in k'[x]$, be arbitrary. By step 3 there exists polynomials $r(x)\in k'[x]$ and $g(x)\in k[x]$ such that $r(x)q(x)=g(x)$.
   We can write
   $$
   z=\frac{p(x)r(x)}{g(x)}=\frac{h(x)}{g(x)},
   $$
   where $h(x)\in k'[x]$ and $g(x)\in k[x]$. By step 1 $h[x]$ is a $k[x]$-linear combination of elements of $\mathcal{B}$. Consequently $z$ is a $k(x)$-linear combination of elements of $\mathcal{B}$.
5. Combining items 2. and 4. shows that $\mathcal{B}$ is a basis of $k'(x)/k(x)$ proving the claim.

Comment: I posted this because my search-fu is weak today. Probably this is a duplicate.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I don't understand every point but I'll think for myself first.

Comment: I don't understand why the fact that $k'[x]/\langle f(x)\rangle$ is a finite dimensional vector space over $k$ implies that $f(x)$ is a factor of a polynomial from $k[x]$. Could you explain more?

Comment: @babybunny A slightly different view: Consider the ideals $I\subset k[x]$ and $I'\subset k'[x]$ consisting of the polynomials $a(x)$ such that $a(T)$ vanishes on all of $V$. Obvious they are ideals of the respective polynomial rings, and $I'$ is generated by $f(x)$. Because $\dim_k V<\infty$ the ideal $I$ is non-trivial. But $I=I'\cap k[x]$, so the non-zero polynomials in $I$ are multiples of $f(x)$.

Comment: Thanks I think I've got it. I still have to write it down in more elementary steps to understand. Did you mean that we define $I'$ to be the kernel of the projection $\phi': k'[x]\rightarrow V$ and $I$ to be the kernel of the $k$-linear map $\phi$ defined as the restriction of $\phi'$ to $k[x]$. Since $\dim_k V<\infty$ and $\dim_k k[x]=\infty$, we have $dim_k I=\infty$ by the rank–nullity theorem.

Comment: I still have a lots of other questions. In point 3, why do we need the first sentence to conclude that multiplication by $x$ is a $k$-linear transformation in $End(V)$? Can't we just say that since multiplication by $x$ a $k$-linear map on $k'[x]$ so it is also on $V$?

Comment: Yeah, I phrased it in an odd way. Let me think about it...

Comment: Thanks for the edit, now I understand the whole proof!

Comment: Glad to hear that!